# Set Clipboard Contents

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to figure out why setting the contents of the system clipboard won't work for me. I programmatically set the clipboard contents. When i use the output part of the code, it works. However, when i try copy/pasting in any text editor, it is blank.

---

hovercraft edit, code from github:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException,
         UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {

      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
            .setContents(new StringSelection("hi there"), null);

      System.out.println(((String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)));

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a *very* small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)? Otherwise it will be hard to guess what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: What is tedious about posting it here? And also, I tried your code, and it works fine for me, I'm seeng "hi there". Is it not working for you?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have to put 5 spaces for each line. And maybe it's because I'm running the program on Linux.

Comment: But again, does the code above not work for you? If so, how? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels When I copy/paste the data into a text-editor, it is blank.

Comment: Then I am indeed perplexed and will have to bow out of this discussion, since your code works for me on my Windows box.

Comment: @Nyx I had the same problem,  my program was exiting before the content was set on the clipboard, solution, add a 100ms delay.

Comment: Linux has several different clipboards, so _how_ you're trying to paste and which clipboard that pulls from can matter.

Answer (score 13):

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;

public class tester{

 public static void main(String[] args){

     // from string to clipboard
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("hi");
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
 }
}
```

This program does it. It will set the String "hi" to clipboard. You can change it to a variable.

Comment: Did you make a mistake on this line "clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);"? You put down selection twice.

Answer (score 0):

Linux cut and paste is a bit weird these days, because there are at least two different ways of doing it.  In short, sometimes it's better to just paste with the middle button, and other times it's better to control-v, and sometimes neither seems to work.

Running autocutsel as a background process seems to help.
http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/

Comment: I tried running it and it did not stop the middle mouse clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and I had the same problem.

Cause: The program was exiting before the content was set on the clipboard.

Adding a 100ms delay fixed it for me.

```java
Thread.sleep(100);
```