# How to Access Clipboard data using Java in Windows?

Tags: java

I want to Access Clipboard data/text in my Java Program in Windows 10 system targeted program. Any code snippets or Class that is used to access the clipboard data?

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code snippet is for accessing and printing the clipboard data in Java:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SystemClipboardAccess {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create a Clipboard object using getSystemClipboard() method
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        // Get data stored in the clipboard that is in the form of a string (text)
        System.out.println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
    }
}
```

Comment: set clipboard reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596368/set-clipboard-contents

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Toolkit#getSystemClipboard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard--):

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;

public static String readClipboard() {
    return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
}
```