# On copy show what was copied in electron

Tags: java, electron, electron-builder

Im working on a little clipboard electron based app

I made a system which right now displays a popup balloon that says ive copied something

However i want it to actually display what was copied in my electron window and be able to keep a list of things ive copied. is there a specific way to do that? 
Also is there any useful clipbaord API's that electron uses?

Thanks,

Code:

```
const CopyHotkey = globalShortcut.register("Ctrl+C", () => {
      if(CopyHotkey) {
      tray.displayBalloon({
        title: "Good Job!",
        content: "You copied something!"
    })}});
```

Comment: I guess this could be answered by using the Clipboard function of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551105/5022959 and setting the String into your content of the tray.

Comment: check out electron's [`clipboard`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard) api