# Cannot access same source HTML as a browser

Tags: c#, html, ajax, web-scraping, bots

I am coming back to work on a BOT that scraped data from a site once a day for my personal use.
However they have changed the code during COVID and now it seems they are loading in a lot of the content with Ajax/JavaScript.

I thought that if I did a WebRequest and obtained the response HTML from a URL, it should match the same content that I see in a browser (FF/Chrome) when I right click and "view source". I thought the actual DOM and generated source code would come later when those files were loaded as onload events fired, scripts lazily loaded and so on.

However the source HTML I obtain with my BOT is NOT the same as the HTML I see when viewing the source code. So my regular expressions that find certain links are not available to me.

1. Why am I seeing a difference between "view source" and a download of the HTML?
2. I can only think that when the page loads, SCRIPTS run that load other content into the page and that when I view source I am actually seeing a partial generated source rather than the original source code. Therefore is there a way I can call the page with my BOT, wait X seconds before obtaining the response to get this "onload" generated HTML?
3. Or even better a way for MY BOT (not using someone elses), to view generated source.

This BOT runs as a web service. I can find another site to scrape but it's just painful when I have all the regular expressions working on the source I see, except it's NOT the source my BOT obtains.

A bit confused at why my browser is showing me more content with a view source (not generated source), than my BOT gets when making a valid request.

Any help would be much appreciated this is almost an 8 year project that I have been doing on/off and this change has ruined one of the core parts of the system.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but you could make the bot hit Ctrl + Shift + I, then right click the HTML tag, select "Edit as HTML", hit Ctrl + A, hit Ctrl + C, and finally use Ctrl + V to paste into a notepad or something. (This is in Chrome.) You would have to hard code the pixel positions of where to click, but it shouldn't be to hard. I know this is possible in Java.

Comment: If you are interested, but don't know Java, I would be willing to write some code for you. I don't like switching languages myself :)

Comment: It seems to have been fixed with the enabling of cookies which I think let each request used the same sessionID rather than different ones which is always a sign of a BOT. But if you have some Java Code that can press buttons on the screen from a BOT I would like to see how you do it,

Answer (score 0):

I have seemed to have fixed it by just turning on the ability to store cookies in my custom HTTP (Bot/Scraper) class, that was being called from the class trying to obtain the data. Probably the site has a defense system to prevent visitors requesting pages and not the JS/CSS with a different session ID on each request.

However I would like to see some other examples because if it is just cookies then they could use JavaScript to test for JavaScript e.g an AJAX call to log if JS is actually on or some DOM manipulation to determine if you are really Human or not which would break it again.

Every site uses different methods to prevent scrapers, email harvesters, job rapists, link harvesters etc inc working out the standard time between requests for 100% verifiable humans and BOTS and then using those values to help determine spoofed user-agents etc. I wrote a whole system to stop BOTS at my last place of work and its a layered approach, just glad the cookies being enabled solved it on this site but it could easily be beefed up with other tricks to test for BOTS vs HUMANS.

I do know some Java, enough to work out what is going on anyway. My BOT is in C#.

Answer (score 0):

**In response to OP's comment**, here is the **Java** code for how to click at different parts on the screen to do this:

You could use Java's [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. I just learned about it a few days ago:

```
// Import
import java.awt.Robot;

// Code
void click(int x, int y, int btn) {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.mousePress(btn);
    robot.mouseRelease(btn);
}
```

You would then run the click function with the x and y position to click, as well as the button (`MouseEvent.BUTTON1`, `MouseEvent.BUTTON2`, etc.)

After stringing together the right positions (this will vary depending on the screen) you could do just about anything.

To use shortcuts, just use the `keyPress` and `keyRelease` functions. Here is a good way to do this:

```
void key(int keyCode, boolean ctrl, boolean alt, boolean shift) {
    if (ctrl)
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    if (alt)
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    if (shift)
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);

    if (ctrl)
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    if (alt)
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    if (shift)
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
}
```

Thus, something like Ctrl+Shift+I to open the inspect menu would look like this:

```
key(KeyEvent.VK_I, true, false, true);
```

Here are the steps to copy a website's code (from the inspector) with Google Chrome:

1. Ctrl + Shift + I
2. Right click the HTML tag
3. Select "Edit as HTML"
4. Ctrl + A
5. Ctrl + C

Then, you can use the technique from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551105/13217548) StackOverflow to get the content from the clipboard:

```
Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
String text = (String) c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Using something like FileOutputStream to put the info into a file:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(  PATH HERE  ));
output.write(text.getBytes());
output.close();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Its great to know how to click points on a page from a BOT for sure. However at the moment just having cookies enabled and the same session ID passed around as I crawl seems to have fixed it. However if they change it again I will probably need to use something like this. The only issue is the content changes each day, a sub menu of links at the top is what I am aiming to collect. Would there be a way to convert say an ID or CSS > span > a.menu into a function to get the X and Y co-ords, as if the length of the content changes all I can go on are the elements/IDs loaded with Ajax content

Comment: @MonkeyMagix The HTML element shouldn't move. On any page you go to and hit Ctrl + Shift + I (right click > inspect doesn't work), the HTML tag will be at the top. After getting the all the code from the clipboard, you should be able to parse it somehow (I'm sure there is a library somewhere). The other option is if the element you are trying to get doesn't move on the screen, you could inspect the element with right click > inspect, then search for the blueish pixels that will appear over the inspected element with ```robot.getPixel```. Moving your mouse to that pixel, edit as html.