# It is possible to paste clipboard line 2-6 directly?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, clipboard

In selenium java

[image]

It is possible to paste clipboard line Apt 2242-6 directly?

If yes, Can you please guide or give me a sample code how to do it, Thanks

example

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#input-235"));
inputElement.clear(); // Clear the input box

(paste clipboard line 3 or line 2)
```

THanks in advance --

Comment: You can try with link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550974/how-to-access-clipboard-data-using-java-in-windows) 

Read the data from clipboard then  you can massage it whatsoever.