# How to prevent window switching when I am entering password using sikuli

Tags: java, security, authentication, automation, sikuli

I am writing a sikuli script to start putty and login to a remote UNIX server. Sikuli would automatically enter login name and password when asked at client side. Now there is a possibility that, while sikuli is entering password someone might trigger window switch either using Alt + Tab or mouse click to open notepad (or any other editor) and steal password. Since we cannot disclose password to user, we are using this script to perform SSO. 
We have tried various options such as entering password character by character and triggering window check at each step, but still there is a possibility of password leak.
Is there any way where we can lock down putty window or disable app switching? 
Is there any other tool where this can be possible? Or is there any way we can handle same using JAVA + Sikuli (using some API or some other tool using Sikuli and Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Putty for something similar, and had troubles entering the password too.

**Option 1**

One option is to copy the password into the clipboard, and then, press right click inside Putty screen (Because right click over putty screen paste text saved in the clipboard). As far as I know, there's no way to write on the clipboard via sikuli Script, but you can do it with Java. One that you have set the clipboard, you can access the clipboard with this command:

```
putty = App.open("path/to/putty.exe")
putty.focus()
password = Env.getClipboard()
rightClick("putty_window.png")
```

The documentation for App class is [Here](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596368/set-clipboard-contents) is an example to set clipboard via java:

```
// Libraries to set clipboard
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;

public class tester{

 public static void main(String[] args){

     // from string to clipboard
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("hi");
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
 }
}
```

**Option 2**

Create a bat file with the content from this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to auto login with putty. After that, convert your bat to exe with **Bat to exe converter**, the second answer on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe).

Comment: thanks man! i thought of the same option, but again there is a risk of someone pasting it again on editor, as it is still on clipboard. Though we can clear it, yet if someone is determined to break it, password is still at risk - If he pastes the same on any editor between paste on clipboard and clear operations. Again its tough but i guess its still a risk!

Comment: So, you want to hide the password?

Comment: yes! customer or any one is not supposed to know the password. is there anyway we can make our item on clipboard inaccessible to other programs?